# Deleting all done items from a SQLite databse

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I need to delete the items that are already done (IS_ACTIVE = 1) from a todo list database, but my code just clears the database. What is my mistake here? [Database example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Ru7.png)

```
    private val todoTable = "TODO_TABLE"
    private val isActive = "IS_ACTIVE"

    fun deleteDone(){
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM $todoTable"
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlSelectQuery, null)
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                val sqlDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM $todoTable WHERE $isActive = ${cursor.getInt(2)} = 1"
                db.execSQL(sqlDeleteQuery)
            }while(cursor.moveToNext())
        }
        db.close()
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to select the rows with `IS_ACTIVE = 1` and then loop to delete them 1 by 1.
Use the method `delete()` to delete them all:

```
fun deleteDone(){
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    db.delete(todoTable, isActive + " = 1", null)
    db.close()
}
```

Here, the 2nd argument of `delete()` is the `WHERE` clause and the sql statement will be interpreted as:

```
DELETE FROM TODO_TABLE WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 1
```

Or simpler:

```
fun deleteDone(){
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    db.delete(todoTable, isActive, null)
    db.close()
}
```

because:

```
WHERE IS_ACTIVE
```

is equivalent to:

```
WHERE IS_ACTIVE = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query.

```
 if(cursor.getInt(2)==1){
 val sqlDeleteQuery = "DELETE FROM $todoTable WHERE $isActive = ${cursor.getInt(2)}" 
 db.execSQL(sqlDeleteQuery)
}
```